# Why jquery.each turn once within function with parameter

Tags: jquery, each

I have a trouble with jquery each. this each block;

```
$(document).ready( function(){  
    $('td.trh').each(function(index) {
        frk=fark($(this).text()); // frk useless variable
        $('td.sure').eq(index).text(frk); // can be $('td.sure').eq(index).text(fark($(this).text()));
    });
});
```

td.trh have date like "2012-03-02 11:25:30" and i have try to calculate the time passing over.. thats perfectly worked for first item but after that every loop stop working.

if i call a function like simdi(); without parameter,each perfectly worked..

fark function like;

```
function saat(trh){ //trh=2012-03-02 11:25:30
    kes=trh.indexOf(' ');
    kes++;
    saat = trh.substring(kes); //saat=11:25:30
    sparca = saat.split(":");
    sTOsn=sparca[0] * 60 * 60; //sparca[0]=11 and 60*60 for hour to sec conversion
    dkTOsn=sparca[1] * 60; //sparca[1]=25 and 60*60 for minute to sec conversion
    sn=sparca[2] * 1;
    sn=sTOsn+dkTOsn+sn; // all of this saat function  for calculate time in sec
    return sn;
}
function simdi() {
    var now = new Date();
    var s = now.getHours();
    var dk = now.getMinutes();
    var nsn = now.getSeconds();
    sTOsn=s * 60 * 60;
    dkTOsn=dk *60;
    rsn = nsn + dkTOsn + sTOsn; // all of this simdi function  for calculate current time in sec
    return rsn;
}
function fark(trh) {
    ssaat=saat(trh); // parameter date calculating in sec
    suan=simdi(); // current date calculating in sec
    snc=suan-ssaat; // calculating beetween parameter date and current date time difference
    hh= snc / 3600 | 0;
    mm= (snc - (hh*3600)) / 60 | 0;
    ss= snc % 60;
    return (hh < 10 ? "0" : "") + hh + (mm < 10 ? ":0" : ":")+ mm + (ss < 10 ? ":0" : ":")+ ss; // and formating time differenc like hour:minute:second
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's still hard to tell what the problem is. What is frk? If it's a global, you do realize it's getting overwritten each time through the loop right? What are the expected and actual behaviors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Statement

```
saat = trh.substring(kes);
```

overrides your function `saat`. Change it to

```
var localSaat = trh.substring(kes);
```

and the next statement to

```
var sparca = localSaat.split(":");
```

You should always use `var` in front of local variables in the function so that they don't become global and polute the global namespace (and cause problems like this).

Comment: thanx for your answer. code perfectly work now. this realy stupid mistake :)

Comment: I can't believe I missed it, I saw all those globals, and thought they were necessary for some reason, but I didn't see that one of the globals was the same name as the function (saat)